# didrangebeacons not called even though didDetermineState is called

Tags: ios, core-location, ibeacon, estimote

I have a set of Estimote beacons. When I use the estimote sdk, I can range for beacons and use it. But the problem is, when I use iOS SDK for monitoring and ranging, didRangeBeacons is not called at all.

I have started ranging as shown below. When I checked using breakpoint, the function is called.

```
- (void) locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didDetermineState:(CLRegionState)state forRegion:(CLRegion *)region
{
    switch (state) {
        case CLRegionStateInside:
            [self.beaconManager startRangingBeaconsInRegion:self.beaconRegion];
            NSLog(@"Region CLRegionStateInside");
```

Answer (score 1):

Please make sure you have gone through the following checklist:

1. You have entered NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription in your info.plist
2. Your property self.beaconRegion is a CLBeacon Region who's UUID matches the UUID you are looking to detect.
3. Your device is iPhone 4S or newer, is on iOS 7 or higher, and has bluetooth turned on

I would change the code to look something like this:

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didDetermineState:(CLRegionState)state forRegion:(nonnull CLRegion *)region {
    CLBeaconRegion *beaconRegion = (CLBeaconRegion *)region;
            if (beaconRegion.major && beaconRegion.minor) {
            } else {
                switch (state) {
                    case CLRegionStateUnknown:
                        // Handle this case when bluetooth is off.
                        break;
                    case CLRegionStateInside:
                        NSLog(@"Inside %@", region);
                        if (![self.locationManager.rangedRegions containsObject:beaconRegion]) {
                            [self.locationManager startRangingBeaconsInRegion:[[CLBeaconRegion alloc] initWithProximityUUID:beaconRegion.proximityUUID identifier:beaconRegion.proximityUUID.UUIDString]];
                        }
                        break;
                case CLRegionStateOutside:
                    NSLog(@"Outside %@", region);
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
```

You only need to range on the UUID, because that will pick up all beacons that match that UUID regardless of major and minor. Also note that you should only attempt to start ranging if you are not already ranging to avoid the extra function call